# If SaveAs location is already open, I get 1004 Error

Tags: vba, excel

Running into a bit of end-user problems with some VBA `SaveAs` code.

The code below executes a `SaveAs` for the current workbook, allows users to select the name, closes the new saved file and reopens the original. This is for an Excel workbook for many users on a server where many people will be constantly opening/closing files.

The problem is when a user tries to execute the code below to save over a file that another user has open, the program displays a Run-time Error '1004': You cannot save this workbook with the same name as another open workbook or add-in., etc.

Does anyone know how to check if the `SaveAs` destination is already open, then display `MsgBox` "File is opened by another user. Please wait until they close or select a different file name."

Any help would be greatly appreciated, can't figure this one out!

```
Sub ExportTrip()
Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
Dim ActBook As Workbook
Dim CurrentFile As String
Dim NewFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False    ' Prevents screen refreshing.

CurrentFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName   ' saves filename of current workbook

NewFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    InitialFileName:=Sheets("Master").Range("B5"), _
    FileFilter:="ARMS Export *.xlsm (*.xlsm),")   ' gets filename for exported workbook

   If NewFile <> "" And NewFile <> "False" Then         'if user doesn't pick name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NewFile, _
        FileFormat:=52, _
        Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False

    Set ActBook = ActiveWorkbook 'declares variable for open workbook
    Workbooks.Open CurrentFile   'reopens original workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActBook.Close                'closes exported workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The error message you quote is different from the situation you describe.  Typically you'd get that message if (for example) you already have a Book1.xlsx open in Excel and you try to save a different open file also as Book1.xlsx

Comment: Thanks Tim! Looks like I had two problems occuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

Start your Error msg from here

```
'// Here msgbox
On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=NewFile, _
        FileFormat:=52, _
        Password:="", _
        WriteResPassword:="", _
        ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        CreateBackup:=False
    Set ActBook = ActiveWorkbook 'declares variable for open workbook
    Workbooks.Open CurrentFile   'reopens original workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActBook.Close                'closes exported workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

and make sure the ErrMsg: is before `End Sub`

.

```
'// Here Err MsgBox
ErrMsg:
MsgBox ("Type your message here."), , "MESSAGE TITLE"

End Sub
```